# Output of installed programs with CSV-Export

Tags: powershell, csv, export, output

I've several problems with the output and export of my current project. I'm using the cmdlet `Get-RemoteProgram` to get the installed Software via Network and registry entries.

This is my code for now:

```
function Get-RemoteProgram ....

$computername = Import-Csv "C:\data\test\test.csv" |
                select -ExpandProperty PCName
$regex = @("Program1|Program2|Program3")
$items = @()

foreach ($computer in $computername) {
  if (Test-Connection $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Count 1) {
    $query = Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName $computer -Property DisplayVersion |
             where {$_.ProgramName -match $regex}
    $obj = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -Name ("Computername") -Value $computer -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $maxcount = $query.ProgramName.Count
    if ($maxcount -gt 1) {
      for ($i=0; $i -lt $maxcount; $i++) {
        $progandversion = $query.ProgramName[$i] + $query.DisplayVersion[$i]
        $obj | Add-Member -Name ($progandversion) -Value "Available" -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
      }
    } elseif ($maxcount -eq 1) {
      $progandversion = $query.ProgramName + $query.DisplayVersion
      $obj | Add-Member -Name ($progandversion) -Value "Available" -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    }

    $obj | Add-Member -Name ("ProgrammVersion$i") -Value $query.DisplayVersion[$i] -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $items += $obj
  }

  $items | Export-Csv c:\daten\inventur\output_final.csv -Append -Force
  Write-Host "$computer has been checked.."
}
```

The problem I now have is that my script does not list all different programs that I am looking for. It should export the computername and afterwards - in the same line - put out an available if the software is installed or keep it clean if the program was not found.

That's the output I get right now:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Computername,"Program1","Program2"
Computer1,"Available","Available"
Computer1,"Available","Available"
Computer2,,
Computer1,"Available","Available"
Computer3,,
Computer2,,
Computer1,"Available","Available"
```

I don't know why the computers are multiple times in the output.

I would like to have it like this:

```
Computername,Program1,Program2,Program3,Program4
Computer1,Available,,Available,,
Computer2,Available,,,,
Computer3,,,Available,
Computer4,,,,
```

Can you help me somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is two-fold. First, you want to update existing data in a CSV, but instead you use `-Append` when you run `Export-CSV`. This explains while more than one row with a given `ComputerName` exists. And second, you are not setting default values for a given `ProgramName`, and thus no properties for programs that are not found anywhere exists in the output CSV. To resolve your first problem, you need to run `Export-CSV` without appending to save your entire data set into your CSV file. And to resolve your second problem, you should pre-fill your new `PSObject`s with properties. Preparation should be done like this:

```
$programs=get-content "programs.txt" # one name one line, or an array of names in @()
$regex='('+($programs -join ',')+')' # regex out of array
```

Then in your main cycle you add this line after call to `New-Object`:

```
$programs | % { $obj | Add-Member -Name $_ -Value "Not found" -MemberType NoteProperty } # create default values
```

Should do. Swap "Not found" for an empty string if you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

After I added the second quote of your answer and additionally added programs in the .txt there is this output now..

How can I let the program check whether the programs in programs.txt are installed or notinstalled on the specified computers in the computerlist?

Comment: Well, you were already doing fine. It's possible that program names have a lil different spelling somewhere, that's why you get wrong output probably. Also check if `regex` is correctly formed.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded version in c# installed programs via windows registry

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace SoftwareInventory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //!!!!! Must be launched with a domain administrator user!!!!!
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            StringBuilder sbOutFile = new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayName;IdentifyingNumber");
            sbOutFile.AppendLine("Machine;DisplayName;Version");

            //Retrieve machine name from the file :File_In/collectionMachines.txt
            //string[] lines = new string[] { "NameMachine" };
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"File_In/collectionMachines.txt");
            foreach (var machine in lines)
            {
                //Retrieve the list of installed programs for each extrapolated machine name
                var registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
                using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machine).OpenSubKey(registry_key))
                {
                    foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                            //Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("IdentifyingNumber"));
                            if (subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", machine, subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey.GetValue("Version")));
                                sbOutFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", machine, subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey.GetValue("Version")));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //CSV file creation
            var fileOutName = string.Format(@"File_Out\{0}_{1}.csv", "Software_Inventory", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mmssfff"));
            using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileOutName))
            {

                file.WriteLine(sbOutFile.ToString());
            }
            //Press enter to continue 
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue !");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
```